# How to update XML node by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom

```
<id>1</id>
<Question>what is .net ??</Question>
<option1>gdsg</option1>
<option2>dg</option2>
<option3>gfdgfdg</option3>
<option4>gfdgfd</option4>
<Marks>1</Marks>
<USERANSWER></USERANSWER>
<CorrectAnswer></CorrectAnswer>
<DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
```

this is my XML format, I want to update  `<USERANSWER></USERANSWER>` node by jQuery - how do I do that when I need only client side update without using webmethods and I have to use only html page and xml file in my application.

Comment: How do you read it?$.get ? Do you want it updated and saved in the server? You need to edit your question and add much more details

Comment: i want to update it by html file....in xml....its examination application and user answer will update the <useranswer> node......

Answer (score 0):

```
$(xml).find('USERANSWER').text("answer");
```

Comment: it comes in chrome console but xml node remain unaffected